# RPC-Model and Xdebug working together?

Tags: php, rpc, xdebug

I'm wondering if its possible to debug using *XDebug* working on an RPC-Application (*based on the RPC-Client-Server-Model*)?

I tried setting a breakpoint on the Server-Side code but its not debugging.

---

I can verify

- that the Browser's Cookie is set correctly
- that X-Debug is working on my IDE (use it on other Application that
  are not based on RPC)

---

I am just wondering if i face any Error i dont see or if its just impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Do You want to debug your client application and seperately RPC server? 
Cookie works for debug session with your client (consumer for RPC) application only.

I think, RPC application must have seperately configuration for xdebug.

eg. in VirtualHost section of RPC vhost

```
php_value xdebug.remote_enable    1
php_value xdebug.remote_connect_back    on
php_value xdebug.remote_autostart    on 
php_value xdebug.remote_enable    on
php_value xdebug.auto_trace    on
```

Comment: I dont know what do you mean vhost. That apache-based Vhost? By the way - can you show me any sense of using this obviously sensless model?